Allowing only access in NGINX when local or connected via VPN
I would like to offer websites via my nginx, some of which are available over the Internet, but others can only be accessed from the local network. I came up with this through BitWarden, for which I need a signed address, but I don't want to expose the service to the Internet.
The solution I found for this was to prohibit all IP addresses and allow the local address range.
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    server_name xxx;

    allow 192.168.178.0/24;
    deny all;

    location / {
        set $upstream https://vault;
        proxy_pass $upstream;
        include proxy_params;
    }

}

First: when I access it from the Internet, I get a 403 http-error as desired.
If I set up a VPN connection via my cell phone using IKEVv2/IPSec PSK, I can successfully access the web server.
According to my Fritzbox, I have the IP address 192.168.178.201.
Now I set up a VPN connection via my cell phone using WireGuard. I can also access local services such as the Fritzbox, I get the IP address 192.168.178.202, but when I call Bitwarden via nginx I get a 403 http-error.
While googling I came across this post: Allowing only local network access in NGINX
But I'm not sure how to configure this and whether this is the actual problem, since I'm using the same device.
This raises my question: How do I get access when using WireGuard analogous to the other VPN connection?
Thank you in advance for your support

What IP address do you have according to Nginx? Does your 403 request show up in its access_log or error_log? That'll tell you what address it sees (possibly an IPv6 address) and what needs to be allowed.

the default log files were empty. I had now added the following line to the server error_log logs/errorvault.log debug; and actually received error logs. The following message appeared:
2024/08/30 10:31:59 [error] 4390#4390: *3 access forbidden by rule, client: 79.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: xxx, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxx"
The IP address listed is my public IPv4 address of the router.

Seems like you have the answer then

what would be the solution? If I allow this IP, I would have to update it regularly, depending on when my provider assigns me a different address. In addition, the aim here was to only allow internal addresses. The question would therefore be how do I get an internal IP address that is used for local network requests when using a VPN connection. The solution could also be to use another VPN server. The question would then be which one offers these functions.

It doesn't depend on the VPN server – all VPNs create a separate network as their function, so this kind of address translation is something that's done completely outside of the 'VPN' proper, in this case specifically Fritzbox weirdness and nothing to do with WireGuard (no, I don't know why it does that).

ah thanks. then I'll try setting up wireguard again as a separate service and not using the integration from the fritzbox. Maybe that will work.
